# Do we need to check CRUD permissions on custom metadata type/custom setting to pass the AppExchange security review

Tags: apex, security-review, custom-metadata

I have an application that we need to upload on AppExchnage but we need to pass the security review so I have a query on the custom metadata type so do we need to check the isAccessible() permission for this or we don't need to check this.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: No, you don't need to check Field Accessibility for Custom Metadata Types.

To expand on this a bit: There is no watertight documentation on this, but the ISVForce Guide does talk you through the steps of the security review here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review.htm?search_text=security%20scanner

The part where they look at whether you're using the required Field Accessibility checks is the code scanner step. You can find the code scanner here: https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/

I've used this code scanner against the Managed Package I've worked on and it doesn't throw errors for missing Field Accessibility checks for Custom Metadata Types. In other words: When the Security Review team runs the code scanner, it will not flag this up for them either.

The best way to confirm that this is the case for your Managed Package too is to run the code scanner yourself and confirm that no errors show up for you either! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a query on a CMD Object in the package, I don't think you need an IsAccessible check (I haven't used one in the past and it wasn't an issue) - with Custom MD, it is more about whether they have access at all (is it protected) or if they have access to Setup - there isn't really the equivalent of CRUD like you would have on a custom object

But if you plan to allow users to update the data, you might need to consider the issues raised in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229710/check-if-user-has-permission-to-update-custom-metadata) post - specifically, whether the user has permission to modify MetaData via the API

Answer (score 0):

With the Summer '19 release and now Winter '20, Salesforce is beginning to enforce CRUD/FLS on Custom Settings. I would assume, though don't know for sure, that future security reviews will make it mandatory for Apex developers to start honoring these permissions.

https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033A00000GimQ6QAJ

> Alert! New Permissions Required for Direct Read Access to Custom
> Settings Sep 4, 2019
>
> by Alerts for Partners
>
> Who is impacted by this change? All partners with AppExchange
> applications or customer solutions that require users to directly read
> or use Custom Setting data, such as when loading Visualforce pages or
> Lightning Components that directly reference Custom Settings.
>
> What is the change? Currently, users can read custom setting data
> using different APIs that are provided by Salesforce without requiring
> specific permissions to do so. Following the “secure by default”
> approach, read access for users without the appropriate permission
> will be revoked as per the timeline below:
>
> With the Summer ’19 release we introduced a new Critical Update
> “Require Customize Application permission for direct read access to
> custom settings”. This Critical Update will be auto-activated on
> January 3rd, 2020 and requires that any user reading custom settings
> has the Customize Application user permission.
>
> In the Winter ‘20
> release we are planning to introduce a new user permission “View All
> Custom Settings”. This permission would enable users to directly read
> any custom setting without having the Customize Application user
> permission
>
> In the Spring ’20 release we are planning to release new
> functionality that would provide more granular control of which custom
> settings can be read by a specific user.
>
> Important: This change does
> not impact scenarios where Apex is being used to read custom settings
> data in system mode. However if Custom Setting objects are being
> passed directly from Apex to a context where user permissions to read
> custom settings are required - such as Visualforce pages or Lightning
> Components - a permission error will occur when displaying these.
>
> What action do I need to take? We recommend that partners test their
> applications and solutions in an environment where the Critical Update
> is enabled. Should you identify scenarios where users require
> additional permissions to continue using your application or solution,
> we recommend the following: Upgrade Permission Sets bundled with your
> application or solution to ensure they contain the appropriate
> permissions (View All Custom Settings or more granular settings)
> Communicate to customers, requesting that their System Administrators
> apply the appropriate permissions to their users via Permission Sets
> or Profiles Where can I go for more information? Review the Summer ’19
> release notes here >

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_settings_access_cruc.htm

Comment: thanks, useful comment.